# Having tests in multiple files

Tags: python, testing, pyramid

I am using pyramids framework for large project and I find it messy to have all my tests in one `tests.py` file. So I have decided to create directory that would contain files with my tests. Problem is, I have no idea, how to tell pyramids, to run my tests from this directory.

I am running the tests using `python setup.py test -q`.

But this of course do not work, after I have moved my tests into tests directory. What to do, to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to make sure `tests` is not just a directory, but a Python package by creating an `__init__.py` in it.

You also need to make sure you name the modules in your `tests` package `test_something.py`.

Most test runners, as part of their test discovery, look for a module or package named `tests`, modules in that package starting with `test_` and expect method names for test methods (on `TestCase` subclasses) to start with `test_`.

The [unittest](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) module describes test runners as:

> A test runner is a component which orchestrates the execution of tests
>   and provides the outcome to the user. The runner may use a graphical
>   interface, a textual interface, or return a special value to indicate
>   the results of executing the tests.

There are plenty of different testing frameworks and hence test runners out there, most extending `unittest` in some way and looking for `unittest.TestCase` subclasses. They may do different types of [test discovery](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#test-discovery), present the results in a different way or gather [code coverage](http://wiki.python.org/moin/CodeCoverage) while the tests are being run.

As for relative imports: You should really try to avoid these. They make it harder to move code around (as you just noticed) and decrease the readability of the imports (where does what code get imported from?). Just use `from myproject.views import my_view` - it's a lot clearer where things live

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found the way to do it. I have just created directory named tests, put my tests inside it and created empty file `__init__.py`. I needed to fix relative imports, or it make strange errors like:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tests'`

I do not really understand what is going on, and what is the `nosetest` role here, but it works.

If someone is able to explain this problematics deeper, it would be nice.

Comment: I stumbled on this while searching for a fix for the AttributeError you've posted.  For anyone else searching for this issue, the problem was resolved when I changed all relative imports to absolute imports (e.g. from .models import Base to from projectname.models import Base)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `nose`
http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
If all your test files start with "Test", `nosetests` should pick them all up and run them.

Comment: Great, so you may not even have to install it. Just make sure your tests are in one folder and their file names start with "test" and go to that directory and run nosetests.