# Pyramid run tests outside of main package

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I'm new to python, so I think it's more of an understanding thing that I am missing for this to not work.

I've started by creating a a new Pyramid project, so that my directory structure looks like:

```
MyProject /
    - myproject /
        - static
        - templates
        - tests.py
        - views.py
    - development.ini
    - production.ini
    - setup.py
    - setup.cfg
```

How ever, I'm adding a lot of my business/service logic to a myprojectlib package under the root package directory, and also created a tests package, like so:

```
MyProject /
    - myproject /
        - tests.py
        - views.py
    - myprojectlib /
        - user_service.py
    - tests /
        - user_tests.py
    - setup.py
```

I've added the **init**.py files to the 'myprojectlib' and 'tests' folder to make them packages, but I can't seem to get the user_tests.py file (and subsequent test code) to be included in the `python setup.py test` command. Only the myproject/tests.py tests are included.

My user_tests.py file contains a single test so far:

```
import unittest

class UserTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_user_can_register(self):

        #code removed for example
```

How I tell python to look for tests in the /tests directory also?

I've had a look at this post, and it seems I am doing all that it suggests: [Having tests in multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145688/having-tests-in-multiple-files)

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Cheers, 
Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `setup` call in `setup.py`, try adding this:

```
  test_suite="tests",
```

as that's the directory that contain your tests.  I typically structure my newer style packages like so and use `nose` to test so I don't have that in my `setup.py`.  Adding that declaration, tests are now executed when `python setup.py test` is called.

Source: https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#test-build-package-and-run-a-unittest-suite

Again, ensure you have a `__init__.py` in the tests directory, else the setuptools test runner will complain about missing `tests` module.

Comment: Thanks very much, that sorted it :). I already had that line in there, but it was pointing to the 'myproject' package.